# How to display multiple value parameter in django rest framework swagger?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

```
Versions:
coreapi==2.3.1
Django==1.11.2
django-rest-framework==0.1.0
django-rest-swagger==2.1.2
django-silk==1.0.0
djangorestframework==3.6.3
```

API endpoint: `/search?filter=("pages")?filter=("people")`

In my SwaggerSchemaView I have defined the filter field as follows:

```
coreapi.Field(name="filters", description="=search(query)", location="query", type="array", required=True)
```

Swagger looks like this:

[image]

now when i provide the values in the value box, it results in the api of format:

```
/search?filter=("pages"),("people")
```

How can I make swagger respect the format I want that is

`/search?filter=("pages")?filter=("people")`

Answer (score 1):

What you need is not supported by CoreAPI out of the box. It will be after this issue gets fixed - https://github.com/core-api/python-openapi-codec/issues/25

But it is available in OpenAPI(Swagger) using `style` and `explode` params - https://swagger.io/specification/

I would recommend writing your own swagger yaml instead of generating it from DRF as DRF is not aligned with Swagger to be able to extract all the required information from it.